# how to recover old python 2.7 cPickled svm model

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pickle

At my new job, they need me to migrate their old code from python2.7 to 3.10. The problem I am facing is that, they have svm models trained and saved as cpickle files. The code to train the same model with newer library version is gone.
When I try to import the model file with `_pickle` in an environment where scikit-learn is installed, it gives the error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.grid_search'`

When I searched about this, it looks like `'sklearn.grid_search'` is now changed to `'sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV'`. However there is no way for me go through pickled model and change these lines.

Is there any way to migrate this for newer versions of python and sklearn?
Just for info, I have an access to python2.7 environment where this model can import properly.

Comment: It's confusing to me because I thought `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV` is used to fit a model, so if you have already trained models, I don't know why unpickling them calls that. Since you do have access to the objects in Python 2.7, perhaps you can figure out which attributes need that module. Perhaps you can just delete those without it affecting the trained models.

Comment: For example, I believe the models contain the support vectors as attributes, and it's been a while since I've used SVM, but I think the support vectors are what determine the model predictions.

Comment: If the models were pickled with a protocol version higher than 0 you could try to unpickle with Python 2.7 and pickle it again with protocol version 0. It may be possible to modify this text based data then.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, Joe and Michael Butscher will try these things and get back to you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.